# Understanding low level initialization in C

Tags: c

I have the following piece of code. It was generated by my IDE and I am trying to understand it.

```
#define TRGMR (*(volatile union un_trgmr *)0xF0250).trgmr
```

Here the timer manager is at the location 0xF0250 according to the data sheet. But what I cant understand is the syntax.

```
union un_trgmr {
    unsigned char trgmr;
    __BITS8 BIT;
};
```

I know about pointers. But I really cant understand what exactly is being done. Could someone please help me out?By the way BITS8 is another struct with bitfields as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char no0 :1;
    unsigned char no1 :1;
    unsigned char no2 :1;
    unsigned char no3 :1;
    unsigned char no4 :1;
    unsigned char no5 :1;
    unsigned char no6 :1;
    unsigned char no7 :1;
} __BITS8;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a way of accessing a memory-mapped register at a fixed address `0xF0250`. You can access individual bits of the registers via the `BIT` field of the union, or the whole 8 bit register via the `trmgr` field. The `#define` just gives you convenient access to the latter, so that you can write, e.g.

```
TRMGR = 0x3f; // write 0x3f to timer manager register
```

Note the use of `volatile` - this is a common technique with memory-mapped I/O registers to ensure that reads/writes always occur as intended and are not optimised away (as they might be with normal memory locations).

Comment: This `volatile union un_trgmr *` creates a pointer to the union. What is the point of the outermost *. Does it tell the union to be located at that address.

Comment: The outermost `*` dereferences the 'pointer to union', giving you the union.  You can use `TRMGR` as an l-value (shown by Paul) or as an r-value: `unsigned char bits = TRMGR;`.  I would argue that for the macro TRMGR, the whole `union` bit is ... overkill.  The macro could perfectly well be written as `#define TRMGR (*(volatile unsigned char *)0xF0250)` and it would behave the same.  This says "treat the memory address 0xF0250 as a `volatile unsigned char *` and access the value stored at that address".  The version with the union does the same, more long-windedly.